# R isn't recognizing the date field I have sent as an input to Rstudio in .csv format

Tags: date, time-series, rstudio, forecasting

[This is my sample data.]

What I had been trying to achieve is Forecasting in R with dates as CSV input via R studio.
When I've tried to change the data type of the Data field in my input using **as.Date**(*my_date_field*, "%Y-%m-%d"), **Class**(*my_date_field*) results in Date only but printing the Values of *my_date_field* results in "NA"s.
So, I am unable to forecast on timeline basis at all.
Please help me out sorting out this issue.

The code I've used for forecasting is:

`library(forecast)
library(lubridate)
FitData <- read.csv("~//Power BI//fit.csv")
Fitdataset <- aggregate(FitData$Metric ~ FitData$PED, data = FitData, FUN= sum)
Fitdataset$`FitData$PED`<- as.Date(Fitdataset$`FitData$PED`, format="%y-%d-%m")
ts_FitData <- ts(Fitdataset$`FitData$Metric`, frequency=12, start=c(Fitdataset$`FitData$PED`[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBRPb.png),1))
decom <- stl(ts_FitData, s.window = "periodic")
pred <- forecast(decom, h = 7)
plot(pred)

`

Comment: can you show a sample data?

Comment: Character,Date,Search
chewbacca,11/4/2015,381
chewbacca,11/5/2015,361
chewbacca,11/6/2015,364
chewbacca,11/7/2015,262
chewbacca,11/8/2015,283
chewbacca,11/9/2015,386
chewbacca,11/10/2015,374
chewbacca,11/11/2015,289

Comment: looks like your date format string should be `format = “%d/%m/%Y”`